# Custom Dialog with a ListView

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a dialog to pop up with a list of comments, and at the bottom the option to add one yourself. (of corse i want to hide txtfirstComment if there is a list populated but i havent hid it yet)

Here'swhat I've done thus far:

```
public static Dialog openComments(Activity a) {
    // custom dialog
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(a);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.dialog_animation;
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.feed_comment);

    String[] listItems = {"item 1", "item 2 ", "list", "android", "item 3", "foobar", "bar", }; 

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(a, R.id.lstCommentList, android.R.id.text1, listItems);

    setListAdapter(adapter);


    return dialog;
}
```

Heres' the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtfirstComment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:text="@string/nocomment" 
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" >

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/lstCommentList" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
           android:id="@+id/line1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="1dip"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:background="@color/darkgrey"/>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" >

    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/txtMakeComment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="@string/makecomment" 
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Don't use stand-alone dialogs, use `DialogFragment` instead. Much more advantageous and less to worry about on device rotation.

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial you can find if you google "android custom dialog". http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: The tutorial does nothing to address my issue with displaying the listview. I cannot get the listview to work properly

Comment: @gunar there's no screen rotation. Can anyone tell me why the listview isn't working?

Comment: Can you post the code where you are showing the dialog?

Comment: as far as I understand, you want to show a custom ListView in a dialog, am I right?

Comment: @HamidShatu Yes but looking online everyone is saying use alert dialog rather than just plain dialog.

Comment: you should use alert dialog...that's the proper way.

Comment: Well the problem i run into is its a custom dialog but in alert dialog the rounded edges show up but they are not transparent. From reading on that they suggest dialogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArrayAdapter second constructor arg you are passing the resource ID of the listview, whereas it should be the id of the layout (Android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1) which contains the textview (the third argument).

Also are you using ListActivity?